# En Linux, ¿se pueden mostrar los directorios en forma de árbol?

Tags: linux

¿Hay alguna forma sencilla en Linux para que, al listar los archivos y directorios, me muestre los directorios organizados en una estructura de árbol?

Por ejemplo:

```
Dir1
--> file1 
--> file2
--> Dir2
    --> file2.1
Dir2
--> file3
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola el comando tree puede ser lo que buscas Te dejo un link http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm Basicamente lista los elementos del directorio en la forma de arbol que mostraste en tu pregunta

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para ver la estructura de directorios en forma de árbol tienes la utilidad `tree`, la cual no suele venir instalada por defecto en la mayoría de distribuciones.

Su instalación desde repositorios depende de la distribución base usada. Para ubuntu/debian:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tree    # Ubuntu    
$ sudo aptitude install tree    # Debian
```

Los comandos más útiles suelen ser:

```
$ tree        # Muestra directorios y ficheros
$ tree -d     # Muestra sólo directorios
$ tree -L X   # Muestra hasta X directorios de profundidad
```

Se pueden combinar ambas opciones. Puedes ver un listado más completo de sus funciones en la página [man online](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) o haciendo uso de dicho comando:

```
$ man tree
```

En MAC OS X se puede hacer uso de esta herramienta por medio de [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Instalar Homebrew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Instalar tree:

```
brew install tree
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta correcta y debería marcarse como aceptada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy util el comando. Una duda, en OSX se instala de la misma manera?  saludos

Comment: @PabloEzequiel He añadido la instalación para OSX a la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias @jose-d-jurado, lo instale de esa manera y anduvo ok

Answer (score 4):

Con `find` también se puede obtener la información deseada:

```
find <directorio> -type d
```

Y se puede formatear la salida para ver la información en modo árbol con `sed`:

```
find <directorio> -type d | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
```

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223233/list-all-directories-recursively-in-a-tree-format/14223313#14223313)

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando [mi respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18255850/1983854)?

Comment: En cualquier caso, si usas el código de otra respuesta, debes citarlo.

Comment: Funciona ok también esta opción, lo bueno de esta versión es que no necesita instalar una librería adicional. El comando es un poco mas difícil de recordar, habría que hacer un alias.

Answer (score 2):

Si se trata más de la información que del formato visual, sin instalación de paquetes `ls -R` permite listar contenidos en forma recursiva (-R).

```
root@box:/etc/dpkg# ls -Rl
.:
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  446 Jun 13  2013 dpkg.cfg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 15  2014 dpkg.cfg.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 11 04:13 origins
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  260 Jun 13  2013 shlibs.default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  253 Jun 13  2013 shlibs.override

./dpkg.cfg.d:
total 0

./origins:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  82 Feb 20  2014 debian
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   6 Apr 15  2014 default -> ubuntu
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 114 Feb 20  2014 ubuntu
```